# FFMPEG multiple screenshots command

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

iam trying to code a function which creates images from video files using ffmpeg.

But now i want to know how can i make that with ffmpeg **commands** exactly, because i use wrapper and now i have some limitations, so i must go in the native way.

So, first of all i have decided to use a Wrapper which is called node-fluent-ffmpeg.

And this is my work-around with the Wrapper:

```
ffmpeg({
        source: `The video file...`,
      })
        .on("filenames", async (filenames) => {
        })
        .on("error", function (err) {
          console.log("Error in filenames section: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        })
        .on("end", function () {
          console.log("Screenshots taken");
        })
        .screenshots({
          count: 60,
          folder: "tmp/",
          filename: "thumbnail-at-%i.png",
          size: "1600x900",
        })
        .on("end", function (stdout, stderr) {
            let newImg = await fs.createReadStream(`/tmp/${img}`);
            destparams = await {
              Bucket: dstBucket,
              Key: "uploaded-" + img,
              Body: newImg,
              ContentType: "image",
            };
           await s3.putObject(destparams).promise();
```

});

**Notes for understanding me better:**

- I still want to make it in node.js
- Let's assume the file is: "The video file..."
- I am taking 60 screenshots from the video in a random way, like it
  does not matter the length of the video it will just take 60 screenshots from start until the end of the video.
- Every screenshot taken will have a prefixed and ordered number and name for every frame.
  **For example:** thumbnail-at-1.png, thumbnail-at-2.png, thumbnail-at-3.png and it continues until it reaches the 60 screenshot limit.
- Every screenshot will be saved with a 1600x900 resolution.
- Every screenshot will be saved in the TMP folder.
- Do not mind reading this: After all I'll upload every screenshot to a s3 bucket.
- I had search trough a lot of old forums, but it seems that ffmpeg has
  a poor documentation (I have been stuck, so hard to understand).

So my main goal is:

**How i can make exactly that function that i have shown in the code sample and the quick notes, with the FFMPEG commands? (Not with the wrapper)**

*(Sorry that i'm trying to make it simpler)*

I mean, **Which commands i must use, with the FFMPEG commands in the following code sample?**

*By the way: it is node.js,*

Do not really know what to do, sorry

```
spawnSync(
      "/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg",
      [
        "-i",
        ``,
        "-f",
        "",
        ``
      ],
      { stdio: "inherit" }
 );
```

**Thanks for your patience!**

**Enviroment:**

- Node.js 12.x
- FFMPEG (4.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem would be getting the duration of the video, so as long as you have ffprobe you should be able to do this:

**Get duration then divide by 60, convert the number to a timestamp**.

`ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams "<FILENAME>"`

Then parse the JSON for `format.duration`, then divide it by the number of screens you want.

Then loop over 60 times to get a single frame at a specific timestamp by doing `dateformat('H:i:s', i * (format.duration / 60))` (pseudo):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i "infile.mp4" -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -f mjpeg "thumbnail-at-0.png"
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i "infile.mp4" -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -f mjpeg "thumbnail-at-1.png"
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:20 -i "infile.mp4" -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -f mjpeg "thumbnail-at-2.png"
...
ffmpeg -ss 00:09:30 -i "infile.mp4" -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -f mjpeg "thumbnail-at-57.png"
ffmpeg -ss 00:09:40 -i "infile.mp4" -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -f mjpeg "thumbnail-at-58.png"
ffmpeg -ss 00:09:50 -i "infile.mp4" -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -f mjpeg "thumbnail-at-59.png"
```

Comment: Wow, buddy thankts
But, i just have two questions:
1-With that command, how can i take these screenshots in a especific resolution?
2-What does  -r and -f mjpeg means?
(Sorry, i am a rookie with the native ffmpeg)